# convert mysql query into laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to get data from two tables one is pharmacies and other is addresses.I can simply do it with query like

```
SELECT pharmacies.*,
       addresses.*,
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(32.5033801) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(74.49884399999999) ) + sin( radians(32.5033801) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM `pharmacies` join 
      addresses on pharmacies.address_id=addresses.address_id 
      HAVING distance < 25 
      ORDER BY distance
```

i want exactly same query in laravel eloquent . pharmacy have one to one relation with address . kindly help me

Thanks

Comment: Laravel provide the custom SQL query, So you can use it. [Link Here](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query like this:

```
DB::table('pharmacies')
     ->select('pharmacies.*','addresses.*',
               DB::raw('(6371 * acos( cos( radians(32.5033801) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(74.49884399999999) ) + sin( radians(32.5033801) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))

     ->join('addresses','pharmacies.address_id','=','addresses.address_id')
     ->having('distance','<',25)
     ->orderBy('distance','asc');
```